# File that can be securely deleted without affecting system

Tags: linux, command-line, files, delete

I'm trying to make one of my shell scripts a little bit safer. I thought about using the default value if for some reason the variable is not defined something like:

```bash
rm -r "${OUTPUT_DIR:-/dev/null/this_path_does_not_exists}"
```

Using the not existing path is a solution I came up with. Then I thought that if there is a system-wide sink (`/dev/null`), maybe there is a file or pseudo-file, that can be safely deleted without affecting the system. So my question is the following - is there a file that is:

- available for deletion without any penalty, functionality loss or data loss
- automatically "regenerated" (it might not be removed by the system in the first place)
- deletion as superuser does not delete it (I was surprised that it's possible to remove /dev/null :))

Comment: "automatically regenerated" ? When ? at boot time or at run time whenever the file is detected missing ? Assumed the latter. So let"s say you get some daemon running and regenerating the file when seen missing, then why do you mind about superuser deleting the file ?

Comment: BTW regarding your first question, then only reasonable answer is : YES! a file YOU would have created in that precise intention (to be deletable without any loss of whatever)

Comment: Do you want a file as in the title of your question or a directory as you say in the question itself? Also, is there any scenario where you would need this and can't just use `mktemp` and/or `mktemp -d`?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of trying to come up with a file (or directory) which always exists yet can also always be deleted, why not explicitly check the variable before using it?

```
[ -d "$OUTPUT_DIR" ] && rm -r -- "$OUTPUT_DIR"
```

If `$OUTPUT_DIR` is empty or points to something which either doesn’t exist or isn’t a directory, this won’t attempt to delete anything.

Comment: It's definitely better solution. I should use it in first place. Maybe I tried too hard this time :). Still I'm curious about the original question.

Comment: @AlexBaranowski You could create a directory or file on a separate small filesystem that you mount read-only. It wouldn't be portable or convenient, but it would be possible.

Comment: @AlexBaranowski is the “safely deleted” requirement at the same level as the three bullet points? In other words, do you need `rm -r` to succeed? (A read-only file system wouldn’t work for that.)

Comment: Actually, I would like rm to succeed, but this is only mental exercise at this point :).

Answer (score 3):

`rm -f` or `rm -rf` does nothing and does not complain if not passed any argument, and you generally want to use `-f` in scripts to make sure the user is not prompted, so you can also do:

```
rm -rf -- ${OUTPUT_DIR:+"$OUTPUT_DIR"}
```

I can't guarantee `rm -rf -- "$OUTPUT_DIR"` would also work as IIRC there are systems where the empty string is treated as the current working directory (which obviously would be dramatic here if `rm` didn't refuse to do it like it refuses to do `rm -rf .`).

```
[ -z "$OUTPUT_DIR" ] || rm -rf -- "$OUTPUT_DIR"
```

Is hardly longer though and more legible IMO.

See also:

```
rm -rf -- "${OUTPUT_DIR:?No output dir!}"
```

For the shell to exit with an error if `$OUTPUT_DIR` is unset or empty.

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/null/something` is guaranteed not to exist, since `/dev/null` is guaranteed to exist and not to be a directory.

Or you can use an empty string. This is guaranteed not to be a valid file name. However, an empty string is risky if the variable is concatenated with something else.

But if you're worried about accidentally using a variable without setting it, turn on [`set -u`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#index-set) (available in all sh-style shells). Then attempting to use an undefined variable is an error, instead of silently using an empty value.

(It's possible to arrange for a file that always exists, and where attempting to delete appears to succeed but leaves the file in place, with a custom [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace). But I don't see how that would help: here you need a file for which `rm` is guaranteed to fail, not one for which it's guaranteed to succeed.)

On the topic of safety: unless you've arranged for `$OUTPUT_DIR` to be an absolute path, it could start with `-`, which would look like an option. So make sure to pass `--` before it when passing it to any command.

```
rm -r -- "$OUTPUT_DIR"
```

Comment: There are systems where `""` is treated the same as `"."` by at least some system calls, so I wouldn't vouch for that *"Or you can use an empty string. This is guaranteed not to be a valid file name"*.